# Difference between executing runables using Netbeans debugger vs without debugger

Tags: java, netbeans

What is the difference between the two.  I have a program which executes a series of runables and it works fine in debug mode but not in live mode.  I'm not sure if certain threads arent getting kicked off or if its potentially a speed factor in which debug mode is running slower and that has some affect.

Its difficult to link code as the code spans multiple classes.  I think the issue is in the following block of code though.

```
/**
 * The class that is used to load the track points in a background thread.
 */
protected class MonitorDirectory extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    public boolean continuing = true;
    /**
     * The executor service thread pool.
     */
    private ExecutorService executor = null;
    /**
     * The completion service that reports the completed threads.
     */
    private CompletionService<Object> completionService = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        //This is a test

        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);

        Path folder = Paths.get(directory);
        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        folder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

        boolean valid = true;
        do {
            WatchKey watchKey = watchService.poll();
            if (watchKey != null) {
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                    if (continuing == false) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
                    if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
                        String fileName = event.context().toString();
                        File file = new File(directory + File.separator + fileName);
                        completionService.submit(Executors.callable(new ReadTrack(file, true)));
                        tracksModel.fireStateChanged(TracksModel.CHANGE_EVENT_TRACKS);
                        timeModel.setLoadingData(LiveTracksProvider.this.hashCode(), false);
                    }
                }
                valid = watchKey.reset();
            }
        }
        while (valid && continuing);
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I'm attempting here is to monitor a folder for new files and then they are passed off to a runnable and read.

Comment: Sounds like a Heisenbug (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug). Good luck.

Comment: actually reading about this just made me think to use comments and output them to see where the code hangs up or where its not getting to.

Comment: You could try that, but be aware that printing something out on the console ( / logging / whatever) might also affect the speed of the execution, which might cause the same effect as debugging (read: your program might work). But give it a try. If it helps you to find the cause like this, you are lucky.

Comment: Actually thank you so much I found the issue using comments.  The File monitor was seeing the file and attempting to read it before it completed being written.  In debug mode because its slower it gave the program time to finish writing the file before reading it.  I just put a threat.sleep(5) in after it see's the file to give it time to process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The File monitor was seeing the file and attempting to read it before it completed being written. In debug mode because its slower it gave the program time to finish writing the file before reading it. I just put a threat.sleep(5) in after it see's the file to give it time to process it.  I give credit to finding my awnser to Joachim Rohde based on his comment.